# Python List of Lists indexes

Tags: python, list, arraylist

```
x = [[0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0]]
```

where the row index is **0,1,2** is to be transpose to **A, B and C**
the columns index is **0,1,2,3,4** is to be transpose to **1,2,3,4,5**
I need to create a function to book a seat i.e. `A1` or `B5`
I have sorted out the row by creating a variable

```
y = ["A","B","C"]
for index, seat in enumerate (x):
    row = y[index]
```

I don't know how to do the columns with regards to the index and then when the user input for instance, A1, it should display Booked if its 0 or display Unbooked if it's 1
don't know if anyone can help?

Answer (score 2):

you could create a dictionary with

```py
x = {
    "A": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "B": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    "C": [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

then check seat availability with

```py
if x[row][column - 1] == 0:
  print("Booked")
else:
  print("Unbooked")
```

with row being "A", "B" or "C" and column being 1,2,3,4 or 5

Comment: Thanks. How do i define the variable row and variable column? I think i'm getting the syntax wrong

Comment: You can do it like this for example: 
x["A"][3]

Comment: So you basically make row be a str of the row you want (A, B or C) and make column be the number of the column you want (1, 2, 3, 4 or 5)